# How to use function with arguments in IF statement in the template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Currently Im trying to use a function that observes a field of a controller/component in ember template (handlebars).

**index.hbs**

```
<div>
   {{ input value=model.field1 }}
   {{if hasFieldError('field1')}}
      <span>This field is required</span>
   {{/if}}
</div>

<div>
   {{ input value=model.field2 }}
   {{if hasFieldError('field2')}}
      <span>This field is required</span>
   {{/if}}
</div>
```

**index.js**

```
hasFieldError: function(val) {
   return true if val is found in an array
}.observes('field1', 'field2'),
```

But this of course returns a build error:

```
{#if hasFieldError('compa ----------------------^ Expecting 
'CLOSE_RAW_BLOCK', 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'OPEN_SEXPR', 
'CLOSE_SEXPR', 'ID', 'OPEN_BLOCK_PARAMS', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 
'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', 'SEP', got 'INVALID'
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Use a computer property not a function

Comment: @Lux that is not my case since i want the hasFieldError to be dynamic. even if i do .property('field1') still this is what i get.

Comment: Please elaborate? What dynamic do you need that you can't do with a computed?

Comment: I use the `function() {}.property('field1')` but this is not a working solution, All i need is to put `{{#if hasFieldError('fieldN') }}` in every required field. However this is still not a valid handlebar syntax. I don't want to write a multiple function that observes every fields. If i am wrong maybe you need to lay a concrete answer so we might be able to understand what you mean? :)

Comment: But in your example the observes is also fixed on field1 not dynamic. Could you please show more code? From where comes field1 in your template? Is this dynamic or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can't call a function from a template, except using an action. You can only reference properties, such as fields and computed properties.
2. Observers are generally not a good idea
3. Are you really trying to determine if the value of field1 is in an array? Let's assume the array is found at array1. Then you could write a helper named `contains`:

`{{#if (contains array1 field1)}}`

But someone has already written this. Welcome to the wonderful Ember community of addons! See https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#contains

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your observer function with a computed property:

```
hasFieldError: Ember.computed('field1', 'field2', function(val) {
   return true if val is found in an array
}),
```

Comment: I guess i need to remove `('fieldN')` in the template and in the function `hasFieldError: function(val)` to `hasFieldError: function() `.

Comment: have a look at `ember-cp-validations`. they generate computed properties, thats maybe what you should do.